# check the pointer position on an element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple reveal caption on hover animation using jquery, I am using hover and animate in jquery. Everything is working fine except in one case - when the hovering on image animation is done and the caption is revealed, if the mouse pointer was on the revealed caption the hovering out animation starts, assuming I hovered out of the image ... so i want to check if the mouse pointer is on the image itself or on the caption before applying the hovering out handler.
edited here is the markup

```js
$( ".img-1" ).hover(function() {
  $( ".cap-1" )
  .animate({ "opacity": "1" }, 100 )
  .animate({ "top": "-=50%" }, 200 )
  .animate({ "top": "+=10%" }, 200 );
}, function() {
  $( ".cap-1" )
  .animate({ "top": "+=40%" }, 300 )
  .animate({ "opacity": "0" }, 100 );
});
```

```css
.img-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  }

.friends-caption {
  position: absolute;
  width: 79.5%;
  height: 37%;
  top: 99%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.7);
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 8%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
  <img src="images/awn1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-1">
  <p class="friends-caption cap-1">Costa Cafe</p>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML, please. It's hard to help without seeing the element structure.

Comment: @isherwood you are right , sorry my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://liveweave.com/C8NNC6
http://jsfiddle.net/zwzoresL/

Why not just apply the hover on the container instead of the image?

```js
$('.col-sm-2').hover(function () {
  $( ".cap-1" )
  .animate({ 
    "opacity": "1", 
    "top": "-=75%"
  }, 300 )  
  .animate({ 
    "top": "+=25%" 
  }, 200 );  
}, function () {
  $( ".cap-1" )
  .animate({ 
    "top": "+=50%", 
    "opacity": "0" 
  }, 300 );
});
```

```css
.img-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.friends-caption {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25%;
  top: 384px;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.7);
  border: none;
  font: 16px inherit;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 16px;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
<img src="images/awn1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-1">
  <p class="friends-caption cap-1">Costa Cafe</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is just like the hover function, it will work fine except if the user accidentally hover over the caption, this will be considered moving out from the image and will apply the mouseout function

Comment: Sorry I was confused with the initial post. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your problem would be to add a pointer-events property to your .friends-caption css rule:

```
.friends-caption {
    /* existing rules */    
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will prevent mouse events from triggering from the caption element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

However, this solution might not have the cross-browser compatibility that you desire. In that case, I think we can do the following to achieve a solution in JavaScript / jQuery:

First, for better organization, let's move the animate steps into their own functions:

```
var animateIn = function () {
    $('.cap-1' )
        .animate({ "opacity": "1" }, 100 )
        .animate({ "top": "-=50%" }, 200 )
        .animate({ "top": "+=10%" }, 200 );
 };

var animateOut = function () {
    $('.cap-1')
        .animate({ "top": "+=40%" }, 300 )
        .animate({ "opacity": "0" }, 100 );  
};
```

We can attach the hover event to the `.cap-1` element as well as the `.img-1` because we want to know when the mouse has entered either element. Next, we need to use a `setTimeout` in our unhover handler because we want time to track if the mouse has moved from one of our targeted elements to the other -- if it has, we can clear our timeout, cancelling our `animateOut` call. Lastly, we will need to track whether our caption is in the "in" state so that we don't allow it to animate in when it is aleady in, or out when it is already out (which would cause the caption to repeatedly jump up or down our page):

```
var hover_timeout;
var caption_is_in;
$('.img-1,.cap-1').hover(function () {
    if ('number' === typeof hover_timeout) {
        clearTimeout(hover_timeout);   
    }
    if (!caption_is_in) {
        caption_is_in = true;
        animateIn(); 
    }
}, function () {
    hover_timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        if (caption_is_in) {
            caption_is_in = false;
            animateOut();
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

I have created a fiddle which can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/76484/sqyc0b61/.

EDIT:

I have realized that my solution is incomplete because the caption can still trigger the hover event when it is in its "out" state. To fix this, we could add a 'container' class to the element that contains the image and caption and add the following css rule:

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76484/sqyc0b61/1/

Comment: mikethedj4's solution of adding the handlers to the container is obviously a much better solution (and one that I'm embarrassed for not having thought of). My fiddle becomes much more elegant this way: http://jsfiddle.net/76484/sqyc0b61/2/

Comment: @mike nice and easy way to do it, thanks. And 76484 your way was smart too , For the sack of learning i liked it ! .. thanks everyone this is the first time i post a question on stack and this was a massive help